# How to add WIFI direct to a python script

Tags: python, wifi, p2p, wifi-direct

I am trying to make a data sharing app in python and I would like to add WiFi direct functionality to it. Now, I did some research and came to an understanding that WiFi direct is a software thing and hence does not require any additional hardware. But I don't seem to find any way to incorporate it in my app. Can you please help?